# discord.py - modal not working i got an error but it doesn't make any sence

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i got an error in the console and i could not find a way to fix it.

```
@tree.command(name="test2", description="My second application Command", guild=discord.Object(id=736684536741625988))
class test2(ui.Modal, title='Questionnaire Response'):
    name = ui.TextInput(label='Name')
    answer = ui.TextInput(label='Answer', style=discord.TextStyle.paragraph)

    async def on_submit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_message(f'Thanks for your response, {self.name}!', ephemeral=True)
```

**Console**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lml\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 16, in <module>
    class test2(ui.Modal, title='Questionnaire Response'):
  File "C:\Users\lml\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\tree.py", line 879, in decorator
    raise TypeError('command function must be a coroutine function')
TypeError: command function must be a coroutine function
```

Answer (score 0):

That command decorator isn't supposed to be there. A Modal is a `class` that you send in your interaction response, not a command.

```py
@tree.command(...)  # <- This shouldn't be here
class test2(ui.Modal, title='Questionnaire Response'):
```

The actual way to send modals is to create an application command, and use the [`InteractionResponse.send_modal()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=send_modal#discord.InteractionResponse.send_modal)-method to send an instance of it.

```py
class test2(discord.ui.Modal, title='Questionnaire Response'):
    name = ui.TextInput(label='Name')
    answer = ui.TextInput(label='Answer', style=discord.TextStyle.paragraph)

    async def on_submit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_message(f'Thanks for your response, {self.name.value}!', ephemeral=True)


# Create a separate command instead of adding the command decorator to the modal
@tree.command(...)
async def command(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    # Send the modal with an instance of your modal class
    await interaction.response.send_modal(test2())
```

Based on the official modal example: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/modals/basic.py

> i got an error but it doesn't make any sence

The error is telling you that the argument for `@tree.command()` must be an `async function`, so it ***does*** make sense because in your case the argument is a Modal...